# How do I autoscroll in Ace Editor?

Tags: ace-editor, autoscroll

I am using an ace editor textbox as a readonly text-area, for the purpose of log output.

Whenever there's a new log entry, I therefor want automatic scrolling.

These are the settings I have now.

```
this.editor.setOptions({
    readOnly: true,
    showGutter: false,
    // showLineNumbers: false,
    vScrollBarAlwaysVisible: true,
    wrapBehavioursEnabled: true,
    autoScrollEditorIntoView: true,
    wrap: true,
})
```

How do I make the box scroll to the bottom on new input?

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution that does not account for the user scrolling up (which is a handy feature), is the following in this case.

```
this.editor.session.on('change', () => {
    this.editor.renderer.scrollToLine(Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
})
```